# spring activemq jmsTemplate.setTimeToLive take longer time more than the specified miliseconds to delete the message

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, jmstemplate

i need to delete a message after specific time so i enabled the explicitQosEnabled and set the time to live.

but i noticed that the message is deleted but it takes longer time than the specified(one minute) so anyone faced this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

Its working as expected. I don't see any issues. If you are using activeMQ can you open your message and see the expiration of the message through the browser. The expiration should have the exact epoch timestamp when the message will expire. You can also use API to jmsTemplate.getTimeToLive on your message.

Gubs